# For two permutations $\sigma$ and $\tau$ and a k-linear function f , how to prove that $ \tau \sigma f = ( \tau \sigma ) f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations

In the book Loring W. Tu An introduction to manifolds of P24 Lemma 3.11, define $ \sigma f (v_1,v_2, \cdots ,v_n) = f(v_{\sigma(1)}, v_{\sigma(2)},\cdots ,v_{\sigma(n)}) $. However if conside $ \tau (\sigma f ) (v_1,v_2, \cdots ,v_n)  $, we have $  \tau (\sigma f ) (v_1,v_2, \cdots ,v_n) = \tau f (v_{\sigma(1)}, v_{\sigma(2)},\cdots ,v_{\sigma(n)}) \\ =   \tau f ( w_1 , w_2 , \cdots , w_n ) = f (w_{\tau (1)} , w_{\tau (2)} , \cdots , w_{\tau (n)}) \\ = f (v_{\sigma \tau (1)} , v_{\sigma \tau (2)} ,\cdots ,v_{\sigma \tau (n)} ) = (\sigma \tau ) f (v_1,v_2, \cdots ,v_n)$, it is $ \tau (\sigma f ) = (\sigma \tau ) f \neq ( \tau \sigma )f $. In another book define $ \sigma f (v_1,v_2, \cdots ,v_n) = f(v_{\sigma^{-1}(1)}, v_{\sigma^{-1}(2)},\cdots ,v_{\sigma^{-1}(n)}) $ is right. So does Loring W. Tu make a mistake ?

Comment: What @DerekHolt says is right. Probably the best way to think about it is that $\sigma.f = f \circ p_\sigma$, where $p_\sigma$ is the function permuting $n$ vectors according to $\sigma$, $p_\sigma(v_1,\dots,v_n)=(v_{\sigma(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma(n)})$. One can easily check that $p_\sigma\circ p_\tau = p_{\sigma\tau}$, and so it becomes clear that $\tau.(\sigma. f) = f\circ p_\sigma\circ p_\tau = (\sigma\tau).f$. If we define $\sigma.f = f\circ p_{\sigma^{-1}}$ instead, we get $\tau.(\sigma. f) = f\circ p_{\sigma^{-1}\tau^{-1}} = f_\circ p_{(\tau\sigma)^{-1}}=(\tau\sigma).f$.

Comment: (cont. of above comment) It is this concept that we are *pre*-composing with $\sigma$, instead of post-composing, that "reverses" the order.

Comment: The three people have voted to close on the grounds of needing detail or clarity. What is unclear about the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand what the definition actually means. For a function $f:X^n\to Y$ and $\sigma\in S_n$, the function $\sigma f:X^n\to Y$ is defined by the rule
$$(\sigma f)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(n)})\tag{1}$$

Note $\sigma$ is applied to the function $f$ to produce the new function $\sigma f$; it's not applied to the value $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. The rule in (1) for applying the new function $\sigma f$ to $n$ inputs is:

1. Permute the given inputs, whatever they are, **by position** using $\sigma$ -- that is, the input in position $\sigma(i)$ should go to position $i$
2. Apply $f$ to the permuted inputs
3. Return the result

Permuting by position is critical because the inputs are not *intrinsically* indexed by the numbers $1,\ldots,n$. They're just elements of $X$. For example if $X=\{\uparrow,\rightarrow,\downarrow,\leftarrow\}$ is a set of distinct symbols, $n=3$, and $\sigma=(13)$, then (1) tells us that
$$(\sigma f)(\rightarrow,\uparrow,\downarrow)=f(\downarrow,\uparrow,\rightarrow)\tag{2}$$
This doesn't change if we write $x_1={\uparrow}$, $x_2={\rightarrow}$, and $x_3={\downarrow}$. In this case (2) says
$$(\sigma f)(x_2,x_1,x_3)=f(x_3,x_1,x_2)\tag{3}$$
Notice in (3) we're **not** applying $\sigma$ to the (arbitrarily chosen!) subscripts of the $x$'s. The only reason that's occurring in (1) is because there the subscripts happen to match the positions of the inputs.

Now if $n$ is arbitrary and $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$, applying this definition repeatedly we have
$$\begin{align*}
(\tau(\sigma f))(x_1,\ldots,x_n)&=(\sigma f)(x_{\tau(1)},\ldots,x_{\tau(n)})\\
&=f(x_{\tau(\sigma(1))},\ldots,x_{\tau(\sigma(n))})\tag{4}\\
&=f(x_{(\tau\sigma)(1)},\ldots,x_{(\tau\sigma)(n)})\\
&=((\tau\sigma)f)(x_1,\ldots,x_n)
\end{align*}$$

Note (4) is correct because we're permuting the inputs $x_{\tau(1)},\ldots,x_{\tau(n)}$ by position using $\sigma$, and $x_{\tau(i)}$ is in the $i$-th position. Another way to see this is to first write $y_i=x_{\tau(i)}$ so
$$(\sigma f)(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=f(y_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,y_{\sigma(n)})$$
and note that $y_{\sigma(i)}=x_{\tau(\sigma(i))}$. Since this holds for all inputs, it follows that $(\tau\sigma)f=\tau(\sigma f)$.